# Why does UNION operator cause datatype change in OracleDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle10g, dataadapter

I have the following query embedded in the procedure `P_GET_TABLE1`:

```
SELECT 
  t1.field1 XXXX
FROM table1 t1
```

`field1` is `NUMBER(12)`. The procedure is exectued in a .NET code using `OracleDataAdapter` and fills a `DataTable` such that `XXXX` is converted into a `long`.

I have another procedure `P_GET_TABLE2`:

```
SELECT 
  t1.field1 XXXX
FROM table1 t1
UNION
SELECT
  0 as XXXX
FROM table2
```

The union, however, seems to cause a change of the datatype such that `XXXX` cannot be converted to a `long`, only `decimal`.

My questions are:

- Why does a `UNION` operator causes the `OracleDataAdapter` to change the datatype?
- Can I force the `OracleDataAdapter` to interpret `XXXX` as a `long`

---

Specifically, this code is used to get data:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
foreach(DataRow row in da.Rows)
{
    long value = (long)row["XXXX"]; // works when P_GET_TABLE1; exception when P_GET_TABLE2 is used; 
}
```

The exception: `'Object of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int64'.'`

Comment: In Oracle datatypes are different than what you would normally expect do a google search on Oracle DataTypes and it will explain the difference in regards to Int Decimals Number, etc...

Comment: What do you get from `select dump(XXXX, 1016) from (SELECT 
  t1.field1 XXXX
FROM table1 t1
UNION
SELECT
  0 as XXXX
FROM table2)`

Comment: I've seen similar issue before.  The solution is to explicitly wrapping the field in a CAST function in all the selects.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit which column are you looking for?

Comment: "Why" is a good question (and it doesn't always have a good answer; there various bugs in Oracle's implementation of UNION). "What to do" is easier; as OldProgrammer said, you can wrap numbers within `cast( ... as number(12) )` - and do it for both members of the `UNION`, since - contrary to the Standard and perhaps to Oracle's own documentation - it is not clear from which branch Oracle will actually read the data type of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hunting this down for you:

The documentation for set operations (including UNION) links to the more general documentation section for "implicit data conversion" - where we can read:

*When manipulating numeric values, Oracle usually adjusts precision and scale to allow for maximum capacity. In such cases, the numeric datatype resulting from such operations can differ from the numeric datatype found in the underlying tables.*

In your example, the second branch of the UNION produces the value 0, not explicitly cast to any precision and scale. So, by default, that 0 is considered of type NUMBER (which has precision 38 and undetermined scale). When you UNION, the data type will be the "max capacity", which is NUMBER.

The solution is to wrap 0 within CAST:  `cast(0 as number(12)) ....`